# How to connect the database using oracle jdeveloper with java?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle JDeveloper. I have to create a database on Oracle JDeveloper, but it is showing the error:

```
Test failed: ORA-28000: the account is locked.
```

I checked with SQL*Plus, and it is not entering the database account.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Log in to the database with `SQLPLUS` (or another client) as a priveledged user and use `ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK;`

Answer (score 2):

The `HR` account is locked and you cannot connect to it until you have unlocked it.

Log in to Oracle (either in JDeveloper, SQL Plus or any other client) as a privileged user (i.e. run `SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA` from the command prompt) and run the command:

```
ALTER USER HR ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```